# Check which tab is clicked / Active in a MS Access form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have created a form in MS Access 2011 in which there are a tab control on top named TabCtl18 in which 3 tabs are page1, page2, page3.
 Under the page1 tab there are another 3 other tabs page11, page22, page33, under three tabs there are 3 reports respectively

Now I want that when a user clicks on pdf icon it check which tab has clicked and print that report.

My Code :

```
Private Sub cmdPrintReportPDF_Click()

    If TabCtl18.TabIndex = 0 Then

        If tab_graph.TabIndex = 0 Then

            DoCmd.OpenReport "Graph_report", acViewNormal
            DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Graph_report"
            DoCmd.Close acReport, "Graph_report"

        End If
    Else
        If tab_graph.TabIndex = 2 Then

            DoCmd.OpenReport "Graph_Report_FieldShifts", acViewNormal
            DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Graph_Report_FieldShifts"
            DoCmd.Close acReport, "Graph_Report_FieldShifts"
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on issue highlighted by @David, here is the way to check name of the `TabPage` selected.

```
if tabControl1.Pages(tabControl1.Value).Caption = "TabPageName" then
    'Do Something
end if
```

Moreover, You can use this code in `Tab` Control `Click` Event to check which Page is active.

Answer (score 3):

The Value (which is the default) property of the tab control is the index of the page with the focus. It starts with zero.

```
If TabCtl18.Value = 0 Then
  'this must be the first page
```

Comment: It's much better to give tab controls meaningful names and use those, since the name doesn't change if you add tabs, but the tab index can change.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @adarsh marecha, but I suggest using the TAG property of the page - using index may not work as intended if the page order gets changed. Also, tabs names can get changed too, which may mean the code fails.

If you set the TAG property to the required value it is likely only you will use it, and it will thus be less likely to fail due to DB changes.

So my code becomes:

```
With Your_Form
   If !tabControl.Pages(!tabControl.Value).Tag = "Your tag" then
       'Do Something
   End if
End With
```